# Update nested list of tables in KDB table

Tags: kdb

I have the below table where I am trying to update the empty schemas of a nested list of table and populate them with results in t1

```
t:flip (`userName`nestedList)!(("user1";"user2";"user3";"user4");(flip (`col1`col2`col3`col4`col5`col6`col7)!(`symbol$();();();();();();());flip (`col1`col2`col3`col4`col5`col6`col7)!(enlist `XXX_XXX;enlist 0b;enlist 2000j;enlist -1j;enlist 1b;enlist 0b;enlist 0b);flip (`col1`col2`col3`col4`col5`col6`col7)!(`symbol$();();();();();();());flip (`col1`col2`col3`col4`col5`col6`col7)!(enlist `XXX_XXX;enlist 0b;enlist 2000j;enlist -1j;enlist 1b;enlist 0b;enlist 0b)))
```

Desired result is t1

```
t1:flip (`userName`nestedList)!(("user1";"user2";"user3";"user4");(flip (`col1`col2`col3`col4`col5`col6`col7)!(enlist `;enlist 0b;enlist 0;enlist 0;enlist 0b;enlist 0b;enlist 0b);flip (`col1`col2`col3`col4`col5`col6`col7)!(enlist `XXX_XXX;enlist 0b;enlist 2000j;enlist -1j;enlist 1b;enlist 0b;enlist 0b);flip (`col1`col2`col3`col4`col5`col6`col7)!(enlist `;enlist 0b;enlist 0;enlist 0;enlist 0b;enlist 0b;enlist 0b);flip (`col1`col2`col3`col4`col5`col6`col7)!(enlist `XXX_XXX;enlist 0b;enlist 2000j;enlist -1j;enlist 1b;enlist 0b;enlist 0b)))
```

//trying to update the t so the count of running below is 4 instead of 2

raze exec nestedList from t //count=2

raze exec nestedList from t1 //count=4

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3):

Here's one way to do it.

```
q)update nestedList:count[i]#enlist flip`col1`col2`col3`col4`col5`col6`col7!1#'(`;0b;0;0;0b;0b;0b)from t where userName in("user1";"user3")
userName nestedList
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
"user1"  +`col1`col2`col3`col4`col5`col6`col7!(,`;,0b;,0;,0;,0b;,0b;,0b)
"user2"  +`col1`col2`col3`col4`col5`col6`col7!(,`XXX_XXX;,0b;,2000;,-1;,1b;,0b;,0b)
"user3"  +`col1`col2`col3`col4`col5`col6`col7!(,`;,0b;,0;,0;,0b;,0b;,0b)
"user4"  +`col1`col2`col3`col4`col5`col6`col7!(,`XXX_XXX;,0b;,2000;,-1;,1b;,0b;,0b)
q)t1~update nestedList:count[i]#enlist flip`col1`col2`col3`col4`col5`col6`col7!1#'(`;0b;0;0;0b;0b;0b)from t where userName in("user1";"user3")
1b
q)count raze exec nestedList from update nestedList:count[i]#enlist flip`col1`col2`col3`col4`col5`col6`col7!1#'(`;0b;0;0;0b;0b;0b)from t where userName in("user1";"user3")
4
```

If you need the where clause to consider the `nestedList` column instead, you could use

```
q)t1~update nestedList:count[i]#enlist flip`col1`col2`col3`col4`col5`col6`col7!1#'(`;0b;0;0;0b;0b;0b)from t where not count each nestedList
1b
```